# Filter rows from dataframe by std devs from mean on each variable

Tags: r, dataframe

Using the iris data set as an example, how can I filter the rows from the dataframe by checking, at each column, if that row's variable is within a certain number of std devs from the mean for that column.  I can do this with a for-loop, but I believe R has a better, faster way to wrangle this data.  I've looked into `dply::filter` but that seems to only work nicely for one variable.  What I want to do is to look at the first column, subset the data based on std_devs from the mean, and use that subset and apply the same function for the next column

```
n <- names(iris[1:4]) #get the non-factors
a <- iris[n]
lapply(a, function(x) a <- subset(a, x >= mean(x) - sd(x) & x <= mean(x) + sd(x)))
```

This returns some type of list (with a data frame embedded in it) the size of iris[n] for **each column**. The results  from the first set don't seem to carry over to the next.  Also, at the end of the process, `a` doesn't seem to be changed.  I don't think you can modify the variable as `lapply` is doing work on it, but if someone can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful - thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain what you want?  " What I want to do is to look at the first column, subset the data based on std_devs from the mean, and use that subset and apply the same function for the next column" is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution if I understood your question correctly.

Notes on the lapply:

- The bracket notation used with the a variable will preserve the data.frame structure you're looking for.. lapply always returns a list (but data.frames are simply a special case of lists)
- The function in the lapply is then applied to each column.  In the function I simply replace all exceptions to your rule with NAs.  Trying to remove these cases at this point of the process would likely end up with different length columns (which wouldn't work in the data.frame structure).

After the lapply I think the base function `complete.cases` would be the simplest way to filter out any rows that contain NAs from the resulting data.frame.  This cuts the data frame down to only 39 observations.

```
data(iris)
n <- names(iris)[1:4] #get the non-factors
a <- iris[n]

a[] <- lapply(a[], function(col) {
  m <- mean(col, na.rm=TRUE)
  s <- sd(col, na.rm=TRUE)
  col[which(col <= (m-s))] <- NA
  col[which(col >= (m+s))] <- NA
  col
})

a <- a[complete.cases(a),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `a` to a list first and then do simple subseting.

If I understand the question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
n <- names(iris[1:4]) #get the non-factors
a <- as.list(iris[1:10, n] )
result <- lapply(a, function(x) x[ x >= mean(x) - sd(x) & x <= mean(x) + sd(x)] )
```

And to convert to data frame

```
plyr::ldply(result, rbind)
```

Comment: In fact as @Adam rightly points out data frame is just a form of a list so the conversion is not necessary.